# How do I ignore the middle of the string in regex?

Tags: regex

For example, the input string is:

> `Application:</b>&nbsp;  </td>`

I want to ignore what's between the following quoations

> `":</b>&nbsp;  "`

Therefore, a match will generate if the following examples strings are found:

> `Application:</b>&nbsp;  </td>`
>
> `Application:  </td>`
>
> `Application:&nbsp;    </td>`

In essence, the regex will ignore the middle part of the string, but it would still be considered a match if it was there. I want to account for the case that the text on the page may not be bold in the future, or more or less white space is added.

Comment: So why not just **hunt** for `<b>` and `</b>` and replace them with `nothing` ?

Comment: What is this `Application:&nbsp;    </td>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that these are the acceptable values of `the middle part of the string`:

- `&nbsp;`
- `</b>`
- whitespace (tabs, spaces, etc)

and that there will always be a colon after `Application`, then you could use the following:

```
Application:(?:&nbsp;|\s|<\/b>)*<\/td>
```

Here we match `Application` followed by `:`, then *either* of the middle string possible values by using a (non-capturing) group `(?:` `)`, zero or more times `*`, followed by `</td>`.

[See this in action with tests](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/eOb).

Comment: No problem :) Feel free to accept this as the answer by clicking the tick.